# Everyone can access my Windows 7 Homegroup file shares - Even Windows XP computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, permissions, network-shares, homegroup

I have 3 computers in my network, two running Windows 7 and one running Windows XP. I've set up a homegroup on both Windows 7 computers. Also, all computers are in the same Workgroup.

The problem is that one of the Windows 7 computers makes all shares accessible to the entire Workgroup instead of just sharing to the Homegroup as it should be.

I created the file share in Windows 7 via right-click in the explorer, then click on "Share For" -> "Homegroup (Read/Write)" (translated from German, so the actual wording may be different).

Also, when I look at the file sharing properties of that folder, Windows Explorer informs me that Users must have a valid account and password for this Computer to access drive shares. Unfortunately this is not true. Being in the same Workgroup is enough to get access.

Homegroup restrictions work as expected on my other Windows 7 computer. When trying to browse those shares from the XP computer, I get a dialog asking for a login and password.

What might cause homegroup restrictions to fail and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are the usernames and passwords the same on both machines?

Comment: The username is, but the password is not. The XP machine does not have a password

Answer (score 1):

How are you accessing the share on the Windows 7 machine?  Mapped drive?  Typing in the UNC path?

It's possible that your Windows XP machine has the correct credentials cached for that machine.  Check in the Control Panel, User Accounts, Advanced Tab, Manage Passwords to see if there is anything there...